# How does asymptotic analysis work with quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, approximations, asymptotics

I am trying to wrap my head around asymptotic analysis when it is applied to quantum mechanics. The best source I have found so far is from MIT (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/808334d09369e3a726f6f20d82315c20_MIT8_04S13_Lec08.pdf), but it leads to me to many more questions. The relevant part is:

[image: A1]

[image: A2]

[image: A3]

[image: A4]

Questions:

- What is the "recipe" to perform asymptotic analysis?
- Why are equations (0.7) and (0.18) true?
- I presume the next line of eq 0.7 is created from plugging $1/x$ into equation (0.6) and solving the ODE? If yes, why do we have a trial solution below equation 0.18?

Reference: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/808334d09369e3a726f6f20d82315c20_MIT8_04S13_Lec08.pdf

In summary, I would be most grateful if you could please explain what is going on at a second year physics student level because this document is very confusing yet is the the best that I have found so far.

Comment: Use MathJax, not images.

Comment: You are asking for an alternative tutorial? Read Bender & Orszag with extreme prejudice.

Comment: I am asking for help explaining what is going on since every other tutorial jumps to computer science and big O, which does not help with physics

Comment: But there is no physics here! You want a joint reading session? Why isn't this posted in MSE?

Comment: As $x \to 0$ we see $1 + 1/x$ becomes dominated by the $1/x$ term, i.e. it's basically equal to the $1/x$ term, the $+1$ is a tiny difference from it, hence the approximate equality. Below (0.7) they are assuming the general solution $f(x)$ breaks up into $h(x)g(x)$, where $h(x)$ solves the approximate equality and deals with the divergence, turning out to be $1/x$ as they show, while $g(x)$ deals with any non-divergent aspects that are ignored in the $x \to 0$ limit. Same idea with (0.18). This website is basically useless if it can't be utilized for a question like this.

Comment: Thank you @bolbteppa!

Comment: I hope you don't imagine the illustrative detour equations (0.17,18) have anything to do with the oscillator equation of page bottom p 6 and then p 7. The former is an *analog* introducing the asymptotic core Ansatz creation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At this level, your instructor has illustrated the broad heuristic "method",

> To summarize, we looked at the
> extreme behavior of the differential equation to peel off a part of the solution.
> We then plugged that back in to get a simpler differential equation to solve.

In particular, he observed the small *x* behavior of (0.6) is (0.7) [the wrong sign is a typo!], and, "fortuitously", it turned out to not lead to an inconsistent/untenable answer: That would be the danger of that asymptotic domain!

- Likewise, for large *u*, (0.17) reduces/simplifies to (0.18) asymptotically.
- Yes, having solved (0.7), he generalizes/morphs it to the ansatz *g(x)/x* which solves (0.6), exactly. Similarly, the ansatz after (0.18) works for it, asymptotically. The (0.18) approximate version for large *u* reassures you of the consistency ("well-behaved") of the normalizable branch of the solution you chose.  He *then* generalizes/morphs this provisory ansatz into the full one above (0.19), now treated *without* asymptotic approximations in (0.19).

So, as he displays, asymptotics educates you about the dangerous asymptotic regions and helps you "peel of" the (potentially disastrous) asymptotic core; hence it inspires you about the type of final Ansatz you devise, which you may then proceed to treat rigorously/exactly. You only get good at this type of guessing/trying through experience. I insisted above, that if you want to get to the bottom of the technique, a course involving Bender & Orszag is valuable.

Comment: To confirm for future readers: 0.7 and 0.18 should be negative? I will check out that source!

Comment: Only (0.7) has a typo sign error.